# Using Jquery in React with Php V8js for server side rendering

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, reactjs, v8

I have created a website that uses react and jquery ajax to load the contents in the page. Now that I want to make my content render from server side for Search engine crawling, I am using php's v8js for server side rendering.

The problem that I am facing is that the jquery ajax calls which is part of react is not working now as the server side rendering using v8js doesnt support the use of jquery in react code or components. I added jquery, jsdom etc as npm package and tried to run the same but dint work.

The error that i am getting is 
"V8Js::compileString():7: TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor" or "$ is undefined"

Kindly suggest some workaround so that i can achieve server side rendering with react and jquery using php-v8js.